# How to add Group field to Custom User?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-rest-framework, django-views

i used this Code in serializer.py

```
    group = Group.objects.get()
    group.user_set.add(self.object)
```

it work fine when the Group Field have just one item and added in DB with no problem.
But when i add more than one item in The Group List Field i am getting an Error:

```
get() returned more than one Group -- it returned 2!
```

what can i do ?

[Image:For one item Work Fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdEAK.png)

[Image:With More than one i am getting This Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dhLj.png)

This is My Full Code:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from . import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
User = get_user_model()

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    confirm_password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    def validate(self, data):
        if not data.get('password') or not data.get('confirm_password'):
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Please enter a password and ""confirm it.")
        if data.get('password') != data.get('confirm_password'):
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Those passwords don't match.")
        return data
    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = get_user_model().objects.create(
            username=validated_data['username'],
            first_name=validated_data['first_name'],
            last_name=validated_data['last_name'],
            email=validated_data['email']
    )
        group = Group.objects.get()
        group.user_set.add(self.object)
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = (
            'username',
            'password',
            'confirm_password',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'groups',
        )
```

Comment: Don't use `get()` if there are more objects. `get()` is used when you know there is only one object that matches your query.

Comment: So what can I use for this ?

Comment: Show the code so we can see what's going on, otherwise it's guessing. But the point remains that your query returns more than one object and therefore exception is raised

Comment: okey i will edit post and add my full code

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to add User to Group, you need to specify the specific Group to which the user will be added. Right now `group = Group.objects.get()` fails with more than 1 group, because `get()` can be used only where there is only one object that matches your query. Without specifying a query filter inside `get()` that will match only one query, Django ORM is querying everything from `Group` model and in case there are more objects / groups, such as Admin and Super Admin, it fails.

You need to change this

```
group = Group.objects.get()
```

to something along the lines

```
group = Group.objects.get(group_name='Admin')
```

and then the newly created user will be added to group named Admin.

Comment: i get this error
`Cannot resolve keyword 'group_name' into field. Choices are: id, name, permissions, user`

Comment: and i want to add more than one group to one user

Comment: group_name was just an example. You haven't posted your models, I cannot tell, which fields your model has. If you want to add user to more groups, do `group_a = Group.objects.get(name='A')` and add user to this group, `group_b = Group.objects.get(name='B')` and add user to this group etc.

Comment: i am using the default django Group model .. i want make it General to add groups to user i want to select by my mouse on many groups and when i press Post button , groups which i selected added to this user like the image i posted above

Comment: i want to tell you that , this serializer for register a new user ,, i am trying to make Api create user with some roles and personal data